# Distinct and joins in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am tryint to fetch distinct `eSignDeviceCode` for same device but for every `eSignDeviceCode` I get a new row.

```
 select 
     count(distinct(eSignDeviceCode)) as units,
     (f.devicename) as devicename,
     (CASE WHEN u.Status=1 THEN  count(u.Status) ELSE 0  END) AS intit,
     (CASE WHEN u.Status=2 THEN  count(u.Status) ELSE 0  END) AS ekyc,
     (CASE WHEN u.Status=4 THEN count(u.Status)  ELSE 0  END) AS esign 
 from applicationdetails u 
 left join esignlogs e  
   on e.ApplicationSlNo=u.SlNo  
 LEFT JOIN fingerprintdevice AS f 
   ON f.SlNo=e.DeviceId  group by e.eSignDeviceCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your group by clause is wrong. Try This:-

```
select 
count(distinct(eSignDeviceCode)) as units,
(f.devicename) as devicename,
(CASE WHEN u.Status=1 THEN  count(u.Status) ELSE 0  END) AS intit,
(CASE WHEN u.Status=2 THEN  count(u.Status) ELSE 0  END) AS ekyc,
(CASE WHEN u.Status=4 THEN count(u.Status)  ELSE 0  END) AS esign 
from applicationdetails u left join esignlogs e  on        e.ApplicationSlNo=u.SlNo  
LEFT JOIN fingerprintdevice AS f ON f.SlNo=e.DeviceId  
group by devicename, u.Status;
```